# LDAP connection over SSL failing in Docker container but working in Openshift Container

Tags: java, ssl, ldap, containers, openshift

Need your help in fixing the container issue.

My issue here is related to LDAP communication over SSL in a Java Application running on WLP server in a container. It seems weird as the same image is working fine in Openshfit but failing in docker server.

Detail:
Java application running over WLP server in Docker Container. LDAP is configured in the server.xml and jks file provided having required certificates. Docker Image was created and Application was working fine in the container.

Docker: Recently, after some code changes, when tried running the container with new image, it started giving SSL related error.
Later on tried with old image, that also gives the same SSL error.

Openshift: Same image(old and new) is running fine in Openshift env.

All certificates are available in the keystore.

Error:
`Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: <xxx.yyy.zzz.com:123> [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=Issuer name, DC=<domain>, DC=abc, DC=com is not trusted; internal cause is:
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error]`

Comment: Can you post the certificate? Is is a self-signed certificate or CA signed? What CA did you use? (No need to post the private key, just the certificate)

Comment: These are self signed certificates. My doubt is, how the same set of certifcates are running fine on Openshift containers but erroring out in Docker containers. LDAP server is same in both the cases.

Comment: There are a couple of options here: 1. The OpenShift env is somehow set to trust this specific certificate (maybe the certificate is installed in the /etc/ssl/certs folder). 2. The JVM in the OpenShift env is somehow configured to avoid trust validation and allow all self signed certificates (maybe via java policy)